# Is normality preserved through the Gram-Schmidt orthanormalisation process?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have a set of vectors (v<sub>1</sub>v<sub>2</sub>) that I convert to an orthanormal set (u<sub>1</sub>u<sub>2</sub>) using the Gram-Schmidt process.

Given a third vector v<sub>3</sub> that is normal to v<sub>1</sub> and v<sub>2</sub>, would $(u_1u_2\frac{v_3}{|v_3|})$ also be an orthanormal set?

Comment: So orthogonal would have been the correct term?

Comment: Orthonormal was the correct term in the context of your question. So you had the right word, just spelled wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, because $v_3$ is orthogonal to the whole plane spanned by $v_1,v_2$, so it is in particular orthogonal to $u_1,u_2$ as these are just two vectors in this plane.